# What is the minimum time you need to Thread.Sleep( ) to ensure DateTime.Now differs?

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the minimum time you need to Thread.Sleep( ) to ensure DateTime.Now differs ?

Given a DateTime has a Ticks property you could argue the following would suffice:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1));
```

which would be fine but does this *guarantee* subsequent calls to DateTime.Now are not equal?

UPDATE:
Appears DateTime precision is hardware dependent so instead I am going to use the following method:

```
public static void SleepUntilDateTimeChanges()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        while(now == DateTime.Now)
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    }
```

Comment: This has a bad code smell about it. Can you explain why you are doing this strange thing in the first place? There is probably a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is for a test case. I need to make sure a DateTime property used to represent a timestamp is not updated when something happens.
So, I have some code 
AssertAreEqual(date1, date2); however I need to be sure this doesnt pass simply because the test runner ran really fast.   
I must admit the code as it stands smells a bit but in the context it is used it is ok. I didnt want to put Sleep(100) everywhere as it slows the test runner down.

Comment: Thread.Sleep has a resolution about 30-50 milli seconds. Sleeping less then that is usually nonsense. You're better of using a high frequency timer and waiting 1 millisecond tick or use a better time container then a DateTime.

Comment: was doing the same. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508208/what-is-the-impact-of-thread-sleep1-in-c

Answer (score 7):

A "tick" is 100 nanoseconds.  Or 1/10,000th of a millisecond.  `Thread.Sleep` operates on *milliseconds*.  While it's true it *accepts* a `TimeSpan`, a value less than a millisecond will be ignored (i.e. same as zero).  According to @wal the resolution of only 10 milliseconds can be guaranteed.  If you wait that amount you should get unique `DateTime` instances.

See also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143140/c-datetime-now-precision) by Eric Lippert which sheds some more light on DateTime precision.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Someone posted:
"From MSDN you'll find that DateTime.Now has an approximate resolution of 10 milliseconds on all NT operating systems."
so I am going to use the method posted in my Update (above)

Comment: Kirk, can you edit your answer 'if you wait a full millisecond' as that may not turn out to be true given the info on the link you sent. I can then accept your answer. :)

Comment: Kirk, Sorry. The resolution of 10 ms cannot be guaranteed, it is hardware specific (according to that link). Cheers.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx